# Can you access a linked arm template on private blob using listkeys?

Tags: azure, templates, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Is there a way to access the linked template on a private blob storage using 'listkeys'. That way I don't need to generate a SAS token each time I deploy. Something along the lines of:

```
"Concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',variables('StorageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('otherResourceGroup', 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('StorageAccountName')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value)]"
```

To go in:

```
"parameters": {
    "sasToken": { "type": "securestring" }
},
"resources": [
    {
        "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
        "name": "linkedTemplate",
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "properties": {
          "mode": "incremental",
          "templateLink": {
            "uri": "[concat('https://storagecontosotemplates.blob.core.windows.net/templates/helloworld.json', parameters('sasToken'))]",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
          }
        }
    }
],
```

MS document doesn't mention it, but it would be easy to deploy without having to generate a token.

In response to Tom as to why I can't use the keyVault, because it still requires it to be input. Here is the code for the token which needs to be inside parameters:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "adminUsername": {
      "value": "cmdbAdmin"
    },
    "adminPassword": {
      "reference": {
        "keyVault": {
          "id": "/subscriptions/c8727b53-932a-4f48-9fa1-00765c554992/resourceGroups/AnsibleTest1/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/ansibletest"
        },
        "secretName": "adminPassword"
      }
    },
```

...and it appears like this in Azure templates. As you can see, you will still need to put in some credentials :(

[image: Azure Templates]

Comment: To answer your direct question, "no".  Can you expand on the scenario a bit more?  Some things that came to mind are 1) do it need to be nested 2) does it need to be secure 3) how many customers need to be able to deploy this way (make KeyVault management more difficult) etc.

Answer (score 0):

> it would be easy to deploy without having to generate a token

```
  "Concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',variables('StorageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('otherResourceGroup', 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('StorageAccountName')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value)]"
```

The code you mentioned that is get the conection string from the storage account.  Azure storage supplies the primary and secondary keys, so we could use the list key API to get the account keys.
But for [SAS token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1) we need to generate it, we need to supply start time ,expiry Time, access permission etc. Based on my experience, there is no the same way as listkey to generated sas token.

> That way I don't need to generate a SAS token each time I deplo

But we could store the SAS token in [Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-whatis), then we could get the value dynamically in the ARM template. Detail info we could refer to this [blog](http://www.codeisahighway.com/how-to-refer-an-azure-key-vault-secret-in-an-azure-resource-manager-deployment-template/).

```
 {
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {

    "sasToken": {
      "reference": {
        "keyVault": {
          "id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resource group name}/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/MyUniqueKeyVaultName"
        },
        "secretName": "secretName"
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm using a SAS token at the moment as a parameter. the reason i ask is because my JSON will be uploaded to Azure templates and then shared to a client. the idea was so that the client didn't have to go and generate a SAS token each time they wished to deploy the machine. also, i have a nested template, so for the keyVault idea to work on the nested template itself it will need to be put in as a parameter, but this doesn't work when you use Azure templates if the idea is for the end user just to fill in a couple of lines/parameters (name, hdd gb, tags, etc) Your ans is correct, but not for me

Comment: For Keyvault the sas token is stored the value in the Azure, not put it as a parameter in the paramter.json .

Comment: We could get the sastoken from Azure keyvault dynamically by **keyvault secretName**.

Comment: Hang on... are you saying I can put that keyvault code in the parent template parameter section, and NOT the *.parameters.json file?